# compile libphp5.so under cygwin

Tags: php, apache, cygwin

After `php make install` under cygwin64, I get the following error:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:246: recipe for target 'sapi/cli/php' failed
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

So, how can I compile "libphp5.so" ???

Comment: What operating system are you running cygwin64 on? Which version of it? which version of libphp5.so? Have you read [this](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-12/msg00093.html)?

Comment: And... on a side note, why on earth are you installing php in cygwin in the first place?!